# Apollo Query variable error when passing state

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

Trying to pass my state of **sortNew** below to the variables in the Apollo query but getting the following 400 ERROR:

**Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400**

**Update:**
Here is the error details:

> [GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$orderBy" of type "String!" used in position expecting type "ItemOrderByInput"., Location: [object Object],[object Object], Path: undefined

This is the current code I'm using thats giving me errors.

Trying to get the **ALL_ITEMS_QUERY** to take the **orderBy** variable. Am I missing something?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Item from "./Item";
import Pagination from "./Pagination";
import { perPage } from "../config";
import Sort from "./Sort";

const ALL_ITEMS_QUERY = gql`
  query ALL_ITEMS_QUERY($skip: Int = 0, $first: Int = ${perPage}, $orderBy: String!) {
    items(first: $first, skip: $skip, orderBy: $orderBy) {
      id
      title
      price
      description
      image
      largeImage
    }
  }
`;

const Center = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
`;

const ItemsList = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 60px;
  max-width: ${props => props.theme.maxWidth};
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
`;

class Items extends Component {
  state = {
    sortNew: "createdAt_ASC"
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Center>
        <Pagination page={this.props.page} />
        <Sort />

        <Query
          query={ALL_ITEMS_QUERY}
          variables={{
            orderBy: this.state.sortNew,
            skip: this.props.page * perPage - perPage
          }}
        >
          {({ data, error, loading }) => {
            if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
            if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;
            return (
              <ItemsList>
                {data.items.map(item => (
                  <Item item={item} key={item.id} />
                ))}
              </ItemsList>
            );
          }}
        </Query>
        <Pagination page={this.props.page} />
      </Center>
    );
  }
}

export default Items;
```

Comment: Check the Network tab and see what the actual response from the server is. 400 is usually thrown on validation errors. The response should include details about what went wrong. You can update your question with the response.

Comment: Thanks got the question updated now with the detailed error

Answer (score 1):

ALL_ITEMS_QUERY expects orderBy to be an enum like so `orderBy: createdAt_ASC` but you're passing in a string `orderBy: String!`. To solve this problem, pass in the enum name to `ALL_ITEMS_QUERY`, that way, your orderBy can be changed dynamically.

An example will look like this

```js
const ALL_ITEMS_QUERY = gql`
  query ALL_ITEMS_QUERY($skip: Int = 0, $first: Int = ${perPage}, $orderBy: NameOfItemsEnum) {
    items(first: $first, skip: $skip, orderBy: $orderBy) {
      id
      title
      price
      description
      image
      largeImage
    }
  }
`;
```

where `NameOfItemsEnum` is the name given to the enum type on the Backend